# Convert Universal app to Windows Phone app only

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing an Universal app capable of running on both Windows Phone and Windows. But initially I want it to be available to phones only because I have not made the Windows part of it. So how can I limit the target devices of this Universal app without creating a new app and without removing the Windows Code from it. I want it to be available to phones only for deployment. Can anybody give a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and Windows Phone apps are submitted separately to the Store. The process for submitting Windows apps is outlined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230835.aspx) and for Phone [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206724.aspx). So you can simply submit one without the other.

You can also stop building the Windows portion of the app using the Configuration Manager if you want to (to save time or avoid compilation errors you don't want to fix yet).